# function wont work from extra load(); html element

Tags: jquery

**index.php**

```
//php mobile detect and load this php
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='../script/classindex.js'></script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='../script/indexcontroller.js'></script>";
?>

<div id="index-main" class="indexMain" data-menu="main">   
<ul id="index-main-ul" class="indexMain__ul"></ul><!-- end of menu-main-ul -->
</div>
```

This is my main page i want to control all my html element here , by here i load 2 js script using php(i need use the php to load js).

**classindex.js**

```
var ClassMenuSetup = function (){};

ClassMenuSetup.prototype.addCss = function (_setroot){
  var case_root = "#" + _setroot;
  switch(case_root){
    case "#getbox":
    $(".getBox").css('box-shadow', '3px 0 0 #6441a4 inset');
    break;
  }
}
```

This the class js which container all my function type and the addCss , is when it match the case , then add the css to the getBox html element.

**indexcontroller.js[ClassMenuSetupObject.addCss function wont work];**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// load extra html element to index page
$('#index-main-ul').load('mainmenu.php');
});

$(window).load(function() {
// the function here wont work , it didt at the css when start.
var ClassMenuSetupObject = new ClassMenuSetup();

var set = "getbox";
ClassMenuSetupObject.addCss(set);
});
```

This js which will load extra html element to index page, then went the page is done , i start the function from classindex.js inside $(window).load

**mainmenu.php**

```
<!-- EXTRA MENU -->
<li class="menuMain__ul__li">
  <ul id="extra-menu" data-menu="main" class="extraMenu">
    <li class="extraMenu__item"><a class="getBox" data-submenu="box" href="">getbox</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

this is the extra html will load to index page , noting much.

the function at index.js wont work.

**Question**

**1.how to i make the ClassMenuSetupObject.addCss work on index.js and add the css to my getBox ?**

Comment: It's because the `load()` method is asynchronous. You're trying to add a class on an element that doesn't exist yet. Put your `ClassMenuSetupObject()` related code in the callback of the `load()` method

Comment: thank for patient reading my post , how i going to do that ? can you give me some guide ?

Comment: $("#bdiv").load("bosses.php #icc10n",function(data){
    // use the data param
    // e.g. $(data).find('#icc10n')
});

Comment: something like this ?

Comment: thank you fixed , thank you again ~ you are the best.